# Prevent Postgresql from logging unique key errors without affecting other error logging

Tags: postgresql, logging

Is there a way to prevent Postgresql from logging ERRORs caused by attempted insertions where a UNIQUE KEY constraint is violated?

I could change the server_log_min directive, but this would disable all ERROR messages and not just those for UNIQUE KEY constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. No such way exists. Short of piping logs via `| grep -v ... |` filter.

Comment: i guess i'll have to do some sort of log file post-processing...

Comment: Actually. Anyone know if there's a way to specify piping via sed script through the conf file?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this just by adjusting the logging mechanism on the server.  You could do it by hacking the source code if you absolutely had to; the relevant code is in src/backend/access/nbtree/nbtinsert.c and looks like this, around line 300:

```
ereport(ERROR,
    (errcode(ERRCODE_UNIQUE_VIOLATION),
        errmsg("duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"%s\"",
            RelationGetRelationName(rel))));
```

You could change the log level there from ERROR to LOG or NOTICE.

Comment: thanks. i thought of hacking source code but it would end up being another maintenance nightmare! :)